# Error while filling color on a buffered image

Tags: java

I am trying to fill a buffered image rectangle with color Red
and i am getting arrayindexoutofboundexception.
could not understand why

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

int[] pixels = {255,0,0};

bufferedImage.setRGB(0,0,width, height, pixels, 0 , width);
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not the expert, but it has something to do with the amount of pixels in your array and the scansize... this code below works. if you are changing the array size from 100 to 99 with a scansize of 0, you're running in the out of bounds exception. if you set the scansize to 100, then you need 10000pixels in your array with a 100x100 image.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        int[] pixels = new int[100];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
            pixels[i] = 255;


        }

        bufferedImage.setRGB(0,0,100, 100, pixels , 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because inside method `setRGB()` one of step is to take the value of your `int [] pixels`.
If you try to set `width=2` and `height=1` than everything will work.
But if higher then your array will not have a value at this index and there will be an exception arrayindexoutofboundexception.